# Call Blade Component on Controller (Livewire Component)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am Trying to call Blade component on Livewire Component (Controller).
But its not working its just return ""

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D0Av.png)

[Rezult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Tqy.png)

I want to be return that is insite this component

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/making-components#inline-components

**Try This**

[image: Try this]

Not sure but may it helps you I did not test it, If it fails let me know I will delete my answer.

Comment: Not really, its only work if u have normal div, But i use "Blade::render()" and its working Good. But Thanks for your answer